# Why did formatting win 7 computers to windows 10 double their CPU-Z bench score?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu, benchmarking

I didn't want to ask this question here. I asked it on superuser but didn't get an answer.

https://superuser.com/questions/1420073/why-did-formatting-win-7-computers-to-windows-10-double-their-cpu-z-bench-score

So I work at a company as an IT guy while I am doing my computer engineering degree. Doing hardware and software maintenance of computers is part of my job. I have had a weird experience with two of the computers. These two computers(one desktop one laptop) were the slowest computers in the company. The laptop is Dell Inspiron N5010 with i3 370M(2 cores, 4 threads) processor. The desktop is HP 500B MT with E5800(2 cores 2 threads) processor.

At first, both of these computers had windows 7 running on them. CPU-Z(1.87.0) benchmark of the desktop was 113(single thread), 227(multithread). The laptop was 82, 267.

After I formatted these computers with windows 10 and ran the same CPU-Z version benchmark, **I got exactly double performance with both computers. Both single threading and multithreading scores got doubled.**

After formatting with windows 10, desktop got 270, 510. Laptop got 180, 520.

What is causing this? Physical core number stayed the same. Logical core number stayed the same. I am baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you upgraded from 32 bit Windows 7 to 64 bit Windows 10?
According to [this FAQ](https://www.cpuid.com/news/51-cpu-z-1-79-new-benchmark-new-scores.html) under the point **What algorithm does the benchmark use...** they state that

> the 32-bit version keeps using the legacy x87 instructions, resulting
>   in almost half of the x64 performance

edit: please remove question here because it is not about code. I answered on superuser as well

Comment: It says i cant delete my question now that people answered it.

Answer (score 0):

If the difference in speed is noticeable, it might have been an issue with the drivers on WIndows 7, or it might have had something to do with [huge pages](https://www.chaoticafractals.com/manual/getting-started/enabling-large-page-support-windows) (enabling huge pages could boost the CPU performance significantly).

If you can't notice the difference in speed/responsiveness, it might just be a bug in CPU-Z (Have you tried the newest version 1.88?).

Going from Windows7 to Windows10 should not on its own result in such drastic changes in performance, the CPU benchmarks should be pretty close. Windows versions are also important, I've seen tests between *Win10 1803* and *Win10 1809* which show approx 10% increase in FPS in favor of 1809 (but that's GPUs not CPUs).